# Healthy consequence of the Akeida?

Tags: psych-mentalhealth, binding-of-isaac

Are there any comment in the Torah, the Mishna or the Gemara, that a post traumatic syndrome disorder was divinely avoided to both Abraham and Yitzhak in the aftermath and in the long run after the binding of Yitzhak?
Conversely, are there enhancements of the mood, the acuity of intelligence or of other qualities of either character, which are stated in the sources above mentioned?

Comment: 1. they were both grown-ups, not kids - 137 and 37 years old. 2. There was no trauma - they were willing to fulfill G-d's wish no matter what. Imagine going to a dentist, he offers you treatment and you prepare yourself for it. He takes the drill, approaches you and says "just kidding, the wrong file, you're free to go." Is it such a big trauma? 3. The sources usually picture the forefathers as fearless, maybe even feelingless intellectuals that streamed all their energies into serving Hashem.

Comment: @Al 1. PTSD affects people of all ages. The fact that they were 137 and 37 doesn’t make them immune. 2-3 you should post as an answer.

Comment: @AlBerko I should clarify for your point 3. They’re not depicted as emotionless, but rather as channeling their emotions to Avodas Hashem. Midrashim describe Avraham as crying at Akeidas Yitzchak, for instance, but he happily put his feelings aside to do the Ratzon Hashem.